# Ignite. active(true)?

Tags: cluster-computing, ignite

when I try to create an apache ignite key value record, I get an error (Can not perform the operation because the cluster is inactive. Note, that the cluster is considered inactive by default if Ignite Persistent Store is used to let all the nodes join the cluster. To activate the cluster call Ignite.active(true).) for work, I use golang and the library github.com/amsokol/ignite-go-client/binary/v1. Since I'm just learning how to work with apache ignite, I don't really understand where I should enable Ignite. active(true) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `control.sh` script:

```
./control.sh --activate
```

You only need to activate the cluster once, so it's generally not a good idea to put it in code.

More in [the documentation](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/control-script).